# How to know if new element is add to the DOM

Tags: javascript

I read about The MutationObserver function or I think it is an interface
but I can't use it
Can anyone tell me?

```
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log("new element has been added");
    console.log(mutation.target.nodeName);
  });
});
```

Comment: You have to call [`observer.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) with a target element and options as arguments.

Comment: ```observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
})``` as this?

Comment: yes I think it is working now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, `MutationObserver` is an interface but you need to call the `observe()` function in order to detect any change in the DOM:

```
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
```

You can try adding this to your code:

```
observer.observe(document, {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});
```

Comment: yes, I did it already, but why you set ```attributes: false, charachterData: false``` what is the difference?

Comment: It was a mistake either of the two must be set to true and that depends on the changes you want to detect: To monitor the node for changes to its textual contents, you set the characterData property of the options object to true: